# Does digits by twitter return back mobile number when validating authheaders on my backend?

Tags: twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

Hello All actually i was integrating digits by twitter for login with otp now when i try to validate the authheaders provided by twitter on my backend then it does not return back mobile number from which i login with digits. Now because of this feature when my user try to signup then i am not able to match the mobile number of the user which i pass as parameter to signup api with the mobile number return by the digits, because of this there can be a possible chances of data tampering and any user can signup in my app with any phone number, please tell me am i missing somthing or if not than how can i overcome this problem ??

Please Help me out of here ??

Answer (score 0):

Digits does return you the mobile number when you verify properly from your server using the auth data that your client got from Digits. Please read this for more info: https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/advanced-setup.html#verify-digits-user